# Count all element occurences in list in cell(by list I mean a string with seperators) in google docs

Tags: google-sheets

I have two tables

Table 1:

```
  | list_of_ids |
1 | 1; 2        |
2 | 3           |
3 | 4; 5; 1     |
```

Table 2:

```
  | id | count |
1 | 1  | 2     |
2 | 2  | 1     |
3 | 4  | 1     |
4 | 6  | 0     |
```

how do I automatically fill in count?

I currently have a very unsatisfying and hacky way of doing it like this:

- list_of_ids is formatted like `;id;id;id;` instead of `id; id; id`
- count `=COUNTIF(range, "*"&";"&id_cell&";"&"*")`

is there a way to do it more properly, so to not force users to write ids in such a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";"; 1; A:A); ";")); 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C2:C="";;IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C; 
 QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";"; 1; A:A); ";")); 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)''"); 2; 0); 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way for it to include 0 as a valid value?

as in, when an id was not in any of the lists.

Comment: @LudwigVonChesterfield see the 2nd formula

Comment: @player0 FYI, heard from Google Flatten is here to stay :)  And they made a Help Center article for it: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en

Comment: @MattKing nice, good to know tho help popup is still missing https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AMLp.png thx for letting us know :)

Comment: @player0

for some reason when I use any samples from StackOverflow, I get a syntax error. I don't know why, but google sheets requires me to use `;` as seperator instead of `,` between function arguments.

also, when I do mend that, I still get a syntax error, and I am not sure why.

Comment: @LudwigVonChesterfield formulae in answer updated to accommodate your semicolon ; needs

Comment: alright, thanks... one final detail. is there a way for me to include data from other ranges into this query? for example, I need to tally up not just all ids from this list-string, but all ids from list-string in rows where column "key" = something, for example "key" is a column before list_of_ids

Comment: @LudwigVonChesterfield possible but hard to tell, can you sjow some example/sample sheet?

Comment: this is pretty much the complete task I needed to solve...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z7wXEOjqLYFqUftPmiOAvU052OpUs5c4aWHDMkCrZPc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: see A15: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14KodSSbkozn__hTMLeO9vXFj2tjoTv84Ni4z9FRCpA8/edit#gid=0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226327/discussion-between-ludwig-von-chesterfield-and-player0).